# Google Analytics 4 - events not visible

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

In migration from GAU to GA4, I'm running into problems tracking some events, specifically those resulting from my form submissions. I have used the Tag Assistant debugger, and I see the events being triggered, but I don't see them when I query for events. An example is a "phone_capture" event.

```
Hit Details (filtered):
    Page Location   dl  https://16v8x.elite80-001.ihousedev.com/contact
    Page Referrer   dr  https://tagassistant.google.com/
    Page Title  dt  Contact Us | New Tester | 111-111-1111 | Paradise Valley AZ Homes for Sale
    Event Name  en  phone_capture
    Event Parameter ep.event_category   lead
    Event Parameter ep.event_label  Contact Us

API Call:
    gtag("event", "phone_capture", {event_category: "lead", event_label: "Contact Us"})

Data Layer
    {
      event: "phone_capture",
      gtm: {uniqueEventId: 14, start: 1684510761995, priorityId: undefined},
      eventModel: {
        event_category: "lead",
        event_label: "Contact Us",
        send_to: "G-6ZMEJ6WQZQ"
      }
    }
```

I generate the report with:

```
$report_params = 
[
    'property'        => "properties/$property_id",
    'dateRanges' => [['start_date'=>'2023-04-28', 'end_date'=>date('Y-m-d')]],
    'dimensions' => [ new Dimension( ['name' => 'eventName'] )],
    'metrics'    => [ new Metric( ['name' => 'totalUsers'] )],
];
$response = $client->runReport( $report_params );
```

I do see other events:

```
EventName         Users
capture               2
first_visit           4
form_submission       2
form_view             2
login                 1
page_view             5
session_start         5
user_engagement       4
```

Is there a different dimension I can use to grab my phone_capture event? Or something else that I have missed? Related - what dimension or other "thing" do I need to see the event_category and event_label?

Comment: Ok, doing more digging, it looks like I might have to create a Custom Dimension and maybe a Custom Metric to get this information. It also looks like I might have to do this at the property level, which would be truly unfortunate (we have thousands of properties for our customers).

Comment: You can use the admin API to automate adding custom dimensions and metrics.

Comment: Thanks, Tony, I have started down that path. Seems a little annoying when the Google tool can see something that I have to do special coding for, but what can you do?